# How to suppress JPA warnings?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, logging, google-cloud-endpoints

I have an App Engine endpoint that has to call `detach()` before modifying some entity fields and returning the response.  But every time I see the following log which is flooding my developer console logs.  How can I suppress this pesky and unnecessary warning?

```
org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl detachObject: Object ... was detached before its changes could be flushed. Changes will not reach the datastore. This is likely the result of a JPA detach() call before flush(), which is a stupid thing to do anyway, but it was your choice.
```

Comment: @LewBloch : But it's not a stupid thing at all!  I don't want to modify my entity on the datastore, but I need to modify a field before sending the response.  I just need to disable that warning.

Comment: if you want to "modify a field before sending the response" then you DETACH the unmodified object and change the field then (in the detached object)!

Comment: @NeilStockton : Well, I do need to change the entity as well. So I do this first before calling detach():

EntityTransaction transaction = mgr.getTransaction();
transaction.begin();
mgr.persist(ticket);
transaction.commit();
mgr.refresh(ticket);

But apparently the entity is still not properly flushed when detached.

Comment: it is flushed at commit. The log would tell you this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to configure the EntityManager FlushModeType to COMMIT and not call anything after calling `commit()`.